# Finding dimensional formula

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis

$$y(x,t)=2A\sin(Kx)\cos(\omega t)$$
$A$ and $x$ are in metre, $\omega$ is angular frequency.
Then find dimensions of $A$ and $K$.

In this equation how can I find the dimension of $K$?

Comment: Can anyone tell me why did i get down vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sine function can be Taylor expanded to yield,

$$\sin x = x-\frac{1}{6}x^3 +\mathcal{O}(x^5)$$

Hence the **argument of the sine function must be dimensionless**, otherwise one would be adding quantities of differing dimension as evinced by the Taylor series. Therefore,

$$[K]=\frac{1}{[x]}=\mathrm{meter}^{-1}$$

to ensure the product $Kx$ has no dimensions. Similarly, $\omega$ in your equation has dimensions of frequency, or inverse time to ensure $\omega t$ is dimensionless.

Comment: I don't see why you need a Taylor series in your explanation.

Comment: @Bernhard: It's to explain/justify why the argument of a sine function must be dimensionless.

Comment: I don't think Freddy understands Taylor series.

Comment: Ok so dimension for A/k is $L^2$. "thanks"

Comment: @Bernhard that's true. But i know that when  any trigonometrical function are used then it become dimensionless.

Comment: @JamalS As trigonometric functions are ratios, it is clear that they don't have dimensions.